# Limit the number of Instances Created Using A constructor with Parameters

Tags: java, object, instance

how can I make my program limit the following instance creation to four so that when I try to create the fifth school it is displays an error message ,"School could not be registered Maximum reached".
Thanks as always

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Header h1 = new Header();
        h1.schoolHeader();
        School s1 = new School("Pascoe Vale High School", "101");
        School s2 = new School("North Melbourne Primary School", "102");
        School s3 = new School("St Aloysuis College", "103");
        School s4 = new School("Coburg High School", "104");
        School s5 = new School("Chuka Nwobi High School", "105");
    }
}
```

---

```
class School {
    public static int objCount = 0;
    private static String regId;
    private String name;

    School(String name, String regId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.regId = regId;
        System.out.println("*** Successfully registered " + getName());
        objCount++;
    }

    public void registerHeader() {
        System.out.println("--- Registering Participating Schools---");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRegId() {
        return regId;
    }
    public void setRegId(String regId) {
        this.regId = regId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Introduce a factory pattern.

Comment: use an array and a global count...or in the School a static counteer

Comment: Well you already have the static School counter in your constructor, throw an Exception if another one is being created?

Comment: To be honest, I just started programming maybe 3 weeks ago and so I am a complete beginner

Comment: @daniu can you please write an example code? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The example code you asked for:

```
static final int ALLOWED_COUNT = 4;

public School(String name, String regId) {
    if (objCount >= ALLOWED_COUNT) {
        throw new TooManySchoolsException("Only " + ALLOWED_COUNT + " schools allowed!");
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.regId = regId;
    System.out.println("*** Successfully registered " + getName());
    objCount++;
}
```

Honestly though, it's not a good idea to do it this way. Much better to allow an infinite number of School objects to be created and have a separate SchoolRegistry class which keeps track of how many schools are registered.

```
class SchoolRegistry {
    static final int MAX_SCHOOLS = 4;
    private List<School> schools = new ArrayList<>();
    public void register(School s) {
        if (schools.size() > MAX_SCHOOLS) throw new TooManySchoolsException();
        schools.add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Two good points: telling on the error what the max number of schools is (so the programmer receives some help), and moving the decision to a SchoolRegistry. The latter could also have a createSchool method to be called a factory class.